# Why can't I simply update array[i] using an assignment statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, indexing, variable-assignment

My function is supposed to replace vowels in an inputted string with capitalized versions of themselves ("a" becomes "A", "dog" becomes "dOg")

It takes a string and creates an array to store and return the changed output

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 
var array=[];
var n =str.length;

for (var i =0;i<n;i++){
if (/[a-z]/i.test(str[i])){

if (array[i]==="a" || array[i]==="e" || array[i]==="i" || array[i]==="o"|| array[i]==="u")
{
 array[i]=array[i].toUpperCase();
};
}
return array;
}
```

Why does my `array[i]=array[i].toUpperCase()` not work to replace the lowercase value with it's uppercase value?

When I print my array, it still has the lowercase value, despite me assigning the newly capitalized value into that index?

Comment: errrr, nothing is in your array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, strings are immutable:

```
var s = "dog";
s[1] = 'O'; // Does nothing!
```

Thus, you must create a new string each time.  You can create a method to do this like so:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character)
{
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
};
```

Here's a working copy of your code that will utilize this function (I fixed a few of your issues):

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character)
{
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
};

function LetterChanges(str) { 
    for (var i =0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        if (/[a-z]/i.test(str[i])) //Note: This test is pretty useless
        {
            if (str[i]==="a" || str[i]==="e" || str[i]==="i" || str[i]==="o"|| str[i]==="u")
            {
               str = str.replaceAt(i, str[i].toUpperCase());
            }
        }
    }

    return str;
}
    
document.write(LetterChanges("dog")); // Print dOg
```

Comment: thanks! this was the answer I was looking for. I wanted to see why I couldn't use the simple assignment statement INSTEAD of the replace method. thanks for your explanation of the strings being immutable and for reading my full question!

Answer (score 2):

What about using a `RegExp` inside the replace function? It is very very very easier!

You can then use a function to elaborate the string to replace and then return it to the `replace` function. In your case it will only return the uppercase value of the vowel.

Here's the code:

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 
    return str.replace(/[aeiou]/g, function(s) { return s.toUpperCase() });
}
```

Example:

```
LetterChanges("hello!");
> "hEllO!"

LetterChanges("aeiou");
> "AEIOU"

LetterChanges("dntrplc");
> "dntrplc"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to initialize your array. That is, this

```
var array=[];
```

should be

```
var array=str.split('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is missing a closing bracket ('}').

Did you know you can use a function to replace matching text?

```
function uppercaseVowels(str){
    return str.replace(/([aeiou])/g, function(a, b){
        return b.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

var s='the quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog.';

uppercaseVowels(s)

/*  returned value: (String)
thE qUIck rEd fOx jUmpEd OvEr thE lAzy brOwn dOg.
*/